# Making a floatable widget in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

In my aplication when there shall be some validation happens, i need a widget or messagebox kind of concept which will pop up in the RIGHT HAND SIDE BOTTOM  of my application for some time (for 5-10 sec) , after that specific time it should disapper .

for eg- when we are getting a mail in outlook some indication is being displayed in the rigt side corner .. i have to implment the same in my application ...
could you please give a small example on this ??

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make a messagebox class to handle the notifications.  Have the class inherit from QWidget, and take a parent in its constructor.

In the constructor, set the position of the message relative to the parent class.  Connect a timeout signal to close the widget.  If you are dynamically allocating them, you may want to set it to delete on close so that you don't need to manage tracking and deleting them.

For very simple operation, you may want to take the message in the constructor and have it show itself as well.